# Not able to update input text boxes from my jquery Ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, razor

I am learning razor pages and how to use AJAX calls. I have created a simple view with a drop down list and a input text box. The web app has the end user use the drop down to pick a first name. The program then uses AJAX to retrieve the last name from SQL and update the input text box that has an ID="LastNameId".  How do I get the data from the AJAX response parameter to pass over to the text input box?
I am seeing the data return as an array to my "response" parameter from the AJAX code. (see image below).  I can see the results when I debug the web app using the f12 tools. So the AJAX call is getting the data and the SQL proc is working.  I can not figure out how to update the input field ID="LastNameID" using the data from the response.

I believe the bug is in the AJAX code section.  From what I have read I should be able to use a line similar to
$("#LastNameId").val(response.LastName)
to pass the value of LastName over to the input field that has the id of LastNameId.  Any ideas what i am doing wrong?

Here is an image of the debug showing the response parameter coming back with data from the stored procedure.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGcsN.png)

**CODE BELOW:
ajax call below:**

```html
function GetIndex()
    {
        $.ajax
        ({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/?handler=Test",
            data: {iIndex: ddlFirstNameIndex},
            contentType: "JSON",
            success: function (response)
            {
                console.log(response),
                $("#LastNameId").val(response.LastName)
            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    }
```

**cshtml code:**

```html
<form>
            <button type="button" class="btn"  id="btn1">Click Me!</button>
           
            <label class="input-group-text" for="FirstNameId">First Name</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="FirstNameId" onclick="GetIndex()" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.Names,"ID","FirstName"))">
                <option value="" selected disabled>Choose from list</option>
            </select>
    
            <span class="row form-inline">
                <label class="input-group-text" for="LastNameId">Last Name </label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="LastNameId" name="LastName" />
            </span>
    
            <span class="row form-inline">
                <label class="input-group-text" for="EmployeeId">EmployeeID </label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="o" name="EmployeeID" />
            </span>
        </form>
```

Comment: Since `response` is an array you need to reference one of its elements: `response[0].lastName`.

Comment: @Jasen - Your suggestion worked. Thank you. I also noticed the capitalization of lastname makes a difference.  I am guessing because my stored procedure is a "select *" instead of "Select LastName"  The internal code is introducing a capitalization scheme on the table columns?

Comment: The response is returning `lastName` and JavaScript is case sensitive so that's what you need to make it work here. The reason it returns that way depends on your server-side code. There are more than one way for the capitalization to change so I can't give you a definitive answer.